# xbee wifi tcp socket keep alive

Tags: sockets, tcp, arduino, wifi, xbee

I am new to Digi's product. I have an arduino yun which runs my tcp socket server and listens for connections. I also have a Xbee wifi S6B module and I want to use it connect to my server. Then I use the XCTU program to setup the network connection for my Xbee. Everything up to this point is fine.

Then, I realize that, the Xbee never connects to my server automatically, it only connects  when I send something from terminal then auto close the connection right away. Can anyone confirm that is this the nature of Xbee and is there anyway to solve this issue (probably there is a setting for it in XCTU but i dont know which one it is)?

Also, I would like to know if there is any way to program the Xbee cause I want the xbee to set the Digital Output pin to HIGH or LOW under some circumstances. I need to know a way to accomplish this.

Thanks.

Comment: 'Xbee never connects to my server automatically, it only connects when I send something from terminal' - you mean at TCP level, (should not happen unless you design in the open/close), or at level 1 wireless link, (happens by design because of the airside protocols that control access to a limited-bandwidth shared medium)?